# delete duplicate data from a line in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove duplicates in a row in excel wish have some data like the picture below  :  [image: excel]

this is what i did :

```
Sub Bouton9_Clic()
Set Rng = Range("H1", "LV1")
Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove Duplicates looks for duplicates in columns not rows.  You will  need to do it with your own code through loops, or transpose the values then use remove duplicates and transpose the values back over the original.

Comment: If you go the loop route, make sure to go in REVERSE ORDER, e.g. For i = LC to 2 Step -1... because you'll be using Columns(i).Delete, this would lead to skipped columns in the long run.  E.g. i = 4, 4 has duplicates so is deleted, what *was* in col(5) is now in col(4), but you iterate your loop, so now you're on col(5) looking at the data that *was* in col(6)